# Selenium webdriver, java,Looping through months in a calendar

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am having a problem handling calendar date picker. I am using selenium web driver and java, I want to select specific date from start and end calendar.

Eg: By default it will show current month (Eg: June) in the calendar. I want to click back until specific month (Eg: May) is found.

Comment: You understand there is no standard "calendar date picker", right? There are like thousands of implementations. You need to post a link to the site you are testing. Also some code to show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using the developer tools of your web browser, identify whether the back button and month heading element have ids or names. If not, you can use the CSS path or XPath to locate the elements. Here's code assuming they have ids.

```
WebElement backButton = driver.findElement(By.id("id of button"));
WebElement monthHeading = driver.findElement(By.id("id of heading"));
```

Once you have these elements isolated, you can achieve your goal using a while loop.

```
while(!monthHeading.getText().equals("specific month"){
    backButton.click();
}
```

This will bring you to your desired month.

Comment: When I tried this,it keeps click back forever, but I want to click back only until I find specific month.

Comment: Actually When I click my date picker there are 2 calendars that are popped, and I check for default months shown in the calendar eg: Jul 2014, but I need to select month May 2014, so I am clicking back.

Comment: Have you checked what the output of monthHeading.getText() is? It may be formatted in an odd way and you may have to write additional code for the comparison check with the month string.

Comment: If the website you're working with is public, posting the URL could help me identify the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I can't share url, but its read only date picker, where I am able to check if current month is not as expected ,then click back and select the date from TO and FROM calendar. 
But I am not able to create complete loop to go through calendar month. 
Eg: if calendar is showing default month(July) further than specific month(May), then it should click back, else (default month is jan) it should click next(Until may month is found) and in both case it should stop when it finds specific month(May is found), then perform some action.